# How to resolve Pytorch "CUDA out of memory" on small complexity model (LBCNN)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm having some trouble implementing a Local Binary Convolutional Neural Network (LBCNN) in Pytorch.

Such model uses fixed convolutional binary filters, they are "randomly" set during the instantiation of the net and keep the same ever after. The only parameter updates are over linear weights that combine the feature maps generated by the filters (this operation is implemented with 1x1 convolutions). The network is then expected to have a small number of learnable parameters and, hence, to be easy to train. But happens that I am receiving the following message when trying to train it:

> RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 128.00 MiB (GPU 0; 15.90 GiB total capacity; 13.75 GiB already allocated; 7.75 MiB free; 15.09 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)

Here is the code for network:

```
class LBCBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_channels=384, n_kernels=512, sparsity=0.1):
        super().__init__()
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.n_kernels = n_kernels

        self.conv_filter = nn.Conv2d(n_channels, n_kernels, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=False)
        kernels = torch.tensor(new_kernel(n_channels, n_kernels, sparsity)).type('torch.FloatTensor')
        kernels.requires_grad_()
        self.conv_filter.weight = nn.Parameter(kernels)
        self.conv_filter.weight.detach_()

        self.weighted_sum = nn.Conv2d(n_kernels, n_channels, kernel_size=1)

        self.shortcut = nn.Sequential()

    def forward(self, x):
        out = torch.relu(self.conv_filter(x))
        out = self.weighted_sum(out)
        out += self.shortcut(x)

        return out

img_width = 32
img_height = 32
class NetLBC(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, lbc_filters=512, n_channels=384, n_blocks=10, sparsity=0.1):
        super().__init__()
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.n_blocks = n_blocks

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, n_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.lbc_blocks = nn.Sequential(*( [LBCBlock(n_channels, lbc_filters, sparsity) for i in range(n_blocks)]))

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.n_channels * (img_height//2) * (img_width//2), 384)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(384, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.conv1(x)
        out = self.lbc_blocks(out)
        out = torch.nn.functional.max_pool2d(out, 2)
    
        out = out.view(-1, self.n_channels * (img_height//2) * (img_width//2))

        out = torch.relu(self.fc1(out))
        out = self.fc2(out)

        return out

model = NetLBC(lbc_filters=512, n_channels=384, n_blocks=50, sparsity=0.1).to(device=device)
```

Comment: Im wondering wether the filters are really not contributing to the number of parameters (as I wished).

Comment: It looks like you have quite a lot of parameters with that many filters and channels. Reduce them.